# Riesz’s representation theorem in a weak form

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain with smooth boundary in $\mathbb{R}^N$ $(N\geq 3)$, $\phi\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ is a solution of $$
\begin{cases}\Delta \phi+ \phi=h & \text { in } \Omega, \\ \phi=0 & \text { on } \partial \Omega,\end{cases}
$$where $h\in C^{\alpha}(\Omega)$ for some $0<\alpha<1$. Wirte the above equation in a weak form: finding a $\phi\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ such that
$$
\langle\phi, \psi\rangle_{H_0^1(\Omega)}=\int_{\Omega}(\phi-h)\psi,\quad \forall \psi\,  \in H_0^1(\Omega).
$$My question is: How to use Riesz’s representation theorem to rewrite the above equation in $H_0^1(\Omega)$ in
the operational form
$\phi=T(\phi)+\tilde{h}$
with certain $\tilde{h}\in  H_0^1(\Omega)$ which depends linearly in $h$ and where $T$ is a compact operator in $H_0^1(\Omega)$. This problem is motivated by using Fredholm’s alternative theorem to study the  existence of solutions.